# Page display issue

Tags: views, files

I have installed drupal print module(latest stable version) and working fine with loads of config unless a big problem that the full content(A view of sets of views) are displaying in one page only,if the content exceeds the current page it displaying on the above of the page. CSS are also working fine.More than one page is not generating.

Any bug or needs config..?

> [image: screenshot]